# reset sequence number for each new month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

From this [Ref.](https://superuser.com/questions/969404/reset-sequence-number-with-change-of-month/969868#969868?newreg=a579c1bc065f4339a8989ffd5c6e630e)

I came across where I need to create a receipt invoice as

1. Year with 4 digits
2. Month 2 digit
3. last digit is the running number from 001 onward

I have a date column (UK Format) in (J2)

Here is the formula I used:

```
=TEXT(YEAR(J3),"0000")&TEXT(MONTH(J2),"00")&TEXT(COUNTIFS($J$2:J2,">="&DATE(YEAR(J2),MONTH(J2),1),$J$2:J2,"<"&DATE(YEAR(J2),MONTH(J2)+1,1))+1,"000")
```

What I expected as I want it to be:

```
202301001
202301002
202301003
202302001 <--- when it comes to 02 (which refers month with 2
digits) the last 3 digits should reset starting base on every each new month
```

The result I get:

```
202301002 <--- with the last digit it should be 001 but instead, it gives me 002
```

as i want to display in (F2)

Do I need a "helper column" to clarify ROW based on the new month's criteria? then use `concatenate` after?
also, I've tried to convert the table to the range but still, it didn't work.

Comment: Try `=YEAR(J2)&TEXT(MONTH(J2),"00")&TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(J$2:J2)=MONTH(J2))),"000")` instead. If you have Microsoft 365, let us know since there are more elegant solutions.

Comment: yes, I work on Microsoft 365. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Then you can use the formula with `SUM` instead of `SUMPRODUCT`. Please test it and let us know if it behaves as required. Also, clarify if the data is in an Excel table since the Microsoft 365 spilling formulas do not work in them i.e. the posted formula (with `SUM`) is probably all there is.

Comment: Yes, the data is in an Excel table. I have tested your code and it worked! (yay) but I'm not sure why it shows "formula omits adjacent cells"...

Comment: @Phernyisthetreename Out of interest, how did you create the structured table reference equivalent of `J$2:J2`? Or did you enter a formula which contained a mixture of structured table references and A1 references? If so, I recommend against doing that - best practice is for structured table formulas to comprise structured table references only.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Maybe you can add your comment to the answer box. It will help a lot more people and also would mark this question resolved. Thanks.

Comment: @JosWoolley I'm not sure if I understand your question... Can you clarify more of what you mean? as I'm a newbie to excel. The reference J$2:J is contain the date... and A1 contains INDEX Number. Nothing to do with A1 when the cell contains different values? Thank you for your reply tho!

Comment: @Phernyisthetreename You said you are using an Excel Table, so I presume column J is within that Table? Tables employ structured referencing when formulas reference cells within them, e.g. `=[@Column1]`. You can of course continue to reference cells within Tables using the standard A1 notation, e.g. `=J2`, though it's not good practice.

Comment: @JosWoolley Oooo, Now, I understand what you mean. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Monthly Running Total

**Excel Table**

- In an Excel table, you will use the column title e.g. `Date`:

[image]

```
=YEAR([@Date])&TEXT(MONTH([@Date]),"00")&TEXT(
    SUM(--(MONTH(INDEX([Date],1):INDEX([@Date],1))=MONTH([@Date]))),"000")
```

**Based On...**

```
=YEAR(J2)&TEXT(MONTH(J2),"00")&TEXT(SUM(--(MONTH(J$2:J2)=MONTH(J2))),"000")
```

```
=YEAR(J2)&TEXT(MONTH(J2),"00")&TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(J$2:J2)=MONTH(J2))),"000")
```

The same array formula as the previous one, but in legacy Excel doesn't have to be entered as an array formula.

Comment: Hello again, I do not understand when I use this code '=YEAR(J2)&TEXT(MONTH(J2),"00")&TEXT(SUM(--(MONTH(J$2:J2)=MONTH(J2))),"000")' It returns what I expected. But with this one above, I run the code but it returns *202301001* for all rows again... I can show you what is return  [Ref.](https://ibb.co/YbjNZ9J)

Comment: Look closer: the column (title) after the first `INDEX` doesn't have a `@`. And why are you using `INDEX(I2,1)`? Maybe best copy the formula to Notepad and replace `Date` with `payment_date`.

Comment: You're the best! `=YEAR([@[payment_date]])&TEXT(MONTH([@[payment_date]]),"00")&TEXT(
    SUM(--(MONTH(INDEX([payment_date],1):INDEX([payment_date],1))=MONTH([@[payment_date]]))),"000")` I removed `@` after `INDEX` and, it works!  Thank you so much for your answer :D

Comment: Hello again. I have 1 more question. With your code, it works perfectly fine for resetting each new month. But I come across where I have to reset by type of invoice too. e.g. **P**202301001 **P**202301001 *until **PN** should be starting new month too. I tried with `COUNTIFS`... but it seems not working. Do I need a helper column for this condition? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That complicates matters too much. You should ask another question with far more details. You could add a link to it in your comments so people following this question could find it more easily.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My question was I want to run numbers by each new month when it comes to the new month, it should be reset as 001 again. [Solved by your code] But I have 2 types of invoices that need to run numbers for each new month as well. So, instead of comparing dates and years. I solved this matter by creating a helper column with a simple formula such as `COUNTIFS` to count the `type of invoice`, `year`, and `month`. and it return as I expected :) But the reason I asked you is that there's probably a formula that works without creating a new column for this.

Answer (score 0):

As you have Excel 365 you can use this `LET`-formula:

```
=LET(checkDate,[@Date], allDates, [Date],
runningNumber,COUNT(FILTER(allDates,
                     (YEAR(allDates) = YEAR(checkDate)) *
                     (MONTH(allDates) = MONTH(checkDate) *
                     (allDates<=checkDate)
                ))),
TEXT(YEAR(checkDate),"0000") & TEXT(MONTH(checkDate),"00") & TEXT(runningNumber,"000")
)
```

`runningNumber` counts all dates returned by the `FILTER`-function.

`FILTER` returns all dates from the same year and month of the `checkDate` that are lower or equal to the check date >> = running number.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. I tested with your code but it didn't give me the result that i expected. It gives me 202301001 for all rows... Anyway, the code that worked for me is the one that @Vbasic2008 uses SUM formula...

Comment: Do you have a column "Date"?

Comment: I have a date column but it still gives the result 202301001... I tried to find what is wrong but I still have no clue why it didn't work with this code.